# I think this is logically strange. Am I right? (Step2 of the proof of Lemma 19.1 on p.161 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, change-of-variable

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> **Lemma 19.1.** Let $g:A\to B$ be a diffeomorphism of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then for every continuous function $f:B\to\mathbb{R}$ that is integrable over $B$, the function $(f\circ g)|\det Dg|$ is integrable over $A$, and $$\int_B f=\int_A (f\circ g) |\det Dg|.$$

The proof of step 2 starts as follows:

> Step2. Suppose that for each $x\in A$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contained in $A$ such that the lemma holds for the diffeomorphism $g:U\to V$ (where $V=g(U)$) and all continuous functions $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$ whose supports are compact subsets of $V.$

I think Lemma 19.1 is a proposition about $g.$
I don't think Lemma 19.1 is a proposition about $f$.
But the author wrote

> the lemma holds for the diffeomorphism $g:U\to V$ (where $V=g(U)$) and all continuous functions $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$ whose supports are compact subsets of $V.$

I think logically the following is right:

> **Condition 19.1'.** Let $g:U\to V$ be a diffeomorphism of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then for every continuous function $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$ whose supports is a compact subsets of $V$, the function $(f\circ g)|\det Dg|$ is integrable over $U$, and $$\int_V f=\int_U (f\circ g) |\det Dg|.$$
> Step2. Suppose that for each $x\in A$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contained in $A$ such that the condition 19.1' holds for the diffeomorphism $g:U\to V$ (where $V=g(U)$).

Or I want to rewrite Lemma 19.1 as follows:

> **Lemma 19.1'.** Let $g:A\to B$ be a diffeomorphism of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Let $f$ be a continuous function from $B$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is integrable over $B$. Then the function $(f\circ g)|\det Dg|$ is integrable over $A$, and $$\int_B f=\int_A (f\circ g) |\det Dg|.$$

Am I right?

Comment: I don't understand your objection. The lemma has the logical form "for all $g$ ... for all $f$ ......" So it's about (arbitrary) $g$ and $f$.

Comment: I cannot see a logical difference between Munkres 19.1 and your last variant  19.1'.